# Dell mouse triggering double-click on almost every single-click

Tags: macos, mouse

My [generic Dell mouse](http://accessories.euro.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=uk&l=en&s=dhs&cs=ukdhs1&sku=570-11147&~ck=baynoteSearch&baynote_bnrank=1&baynote_irrank=0) behaves pretty strange compared to all other mice I have used with my MacBook. Almost every single-click is treated as if it were a double-click. Both the right and left button. The same mouse does not exhibit this behavior under Windows nor Ubuntu Linux.

I have searched and found hints that I should reduce the double-click speed setting in System Preferences: Mouse. But the setting is already as low as it can go.

I find this mouse very comfortable and want to continue to use it. I hope someone can offer another suggestion on how to correct this odd behaivor.

Comment: I have a very similar Dell mouse as well, and also would prefer to not replace it because I find it very comfortable. Were you ever able to solve this problem?

Comment: @houbysoft, no I eventually stopped using it. Despite it being very comfortable. I haven’t really found any other mice suitable for small hands, which is my problem. I’m currently using the medium-sized [Zowie FK2](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00QIH1GD4/?tag=sligfutu-20) with Linux, Max, and Windows. No problems like the above Dell mouse.

Comment: argh I have the opposite problem, the other mice are too small & not heavy enough, I'm using a super old fat Dell mouse. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Aren’t all mice made for giant hands? That is how it looks from my perspective, at least. Good luck finding a replacement, any how.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this mouse behaves differently on a different computer, I would say that the mouse is bad.

I work for a company that uses Dell almost exclusively, and I can tell you that this is exactly what happens when the mouse starts failing. They begin intermittently processing single clicks as double clicks.

We throw them away when this starts happening.

Answer (score 1):

I had a Kensington Trackball which was doing the exact same thing.  I read a bunch of boards and nothing worked.  I threw it away and bought a brand new one. Problem solved! Turns our it was a hardware issue. I have read that other people with the same issue have discovered it is not software based too.

Answer (score -2):

You need to reset you PRAM

Resetting PRAM and NVRAM

1. Shut down the computer.
2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command, Option, P, and R. You will need to hold these keys down simultaneously in step 4.

3.Turn on the computer.

4.Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys. You must press this key combination before the gray screen appears.

5.Hold the keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second time.

6.Release the keys.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4155496?tstart=0

Answer (score -3):

My suggestion is that you avoid using a Dell, or any other Windows manufacturer's mouse, for that matter, on a Mac computer.

Comment: Actually, from what I have seen, Macs *typically* support peripherals that have been manufactured from other Windows companies quite well.